# Scala equivalent of Java 8 :: (double colon) operator

Tags: java, scala

I need to handle Java 8 stream from Scala. What's the equivalent of Java 8 `::` operator in Scala?

```
// Java
IntStream.range(1, 4)
  .forEach(System.out::println);

// Scala
IntStream.range(1, 4)
  .forEach() // <- ???
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `-Xexperimental` when compiling or running the REPL in order to access the experimental feature of converting Scala functions into the desired Java SAMs:

```
IntStream.range(1, 4).forEach(System.out.println(_))
```

Comment: Thank you. Thought this might be what I wanted, I got `error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => System.out.println(x$1))`. Any idea?

Comment: @Shouichi works for me with the 2.11.4 REPL, as written above.  I suppose it truly is an experimental feature!  Maybe try playing around with the different syntax variants (e.g. `x => f(x)`, `f _`, `f(_)`, and `f`).  Worst comes to worst just implement the `IntConsumer` interface.

Comment: Seems like it really is! I don't want to use experimental feature in the production system and implement Java's stream interface. Than you again :)

Answer (score 2):

This is as simple as:

```
scala> (1 to 4).foreach(println)
1
2
3
4
```

In Scala, referencing a method without providing an argument, such as:

```
def fn(arg: SomeType)

(collection_of_some_type).foreach(fn)
```

is desugared into

```
(collection_of_some_type).foreach(fn(_))
```

which in turn translates to:

```
(collection_of_some_type).foreach(next_entry => fn(next_entry))
```

Comment: Thank you but what I need to do is handling Java stream API, not achieving the same thing.

Comment: So you need to precise your question

Comment: @Shouichi so you should be more specific in what are you trying to achieve. In Java, you have to use special operators to access function as a variable. In Scala, there is no need for special operators. For example, `System.out::println` will be `java.lang.System.out.println`, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent for method reference in scala would be the following:

```
IntStream.range(1, 4)
  .forEach(System.out.println _)
```

Comment: This doesn't work because it doesn't satisfy type system.